# Reactive form validator is not working on back button (browser)- angular

Tags: angular

I am facing one problem during my development i have created the login form with reactive validation. it is working fine but when i move to different component (like create account) then click on back button/image to come on home page then validation message () stop to display the error but when i click on the submit button it show invalid state but no message is coming. Can someboday help me why this is happening. here is the example:

```html
<Form class="" [formGroup]="loginForm" novalidate>           
<input matInput formControlName="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" #email> 
 <mat-error>
required
 </mat-error>
</Form>
```

First time it is showing but after back button click it is not working i need to refresh the page then it  started working.

Comment: Post your code here which you tried without that can not find whats the issue, or create stackblitz example.

Comment: Sorry @KamranKhatti, I added the code now . This is just example of the main login.component.ts. when i move to signup.component.ts then click on back button then this validation stop working. I Need to refresh the page every time then it started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. this is happened due to the css. Actually textbox & Button hide the error in the screen . when i give more gap between textbox and button then error was displaying. so textbox/button height override the error therefore we are not able to see.